# Are we still need CSRF cookie in Django when SAMESITE enable?

Tags: python, django

There is the samesite cooike that can protect user from CSRF attack. so are we still need enable the Django's `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` or we can safely disable it now?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by this question. Could you add some more context?

Comment: Is there a specific reason *why* you want to disable CSRF validation? It is usually better to have multiple security layers.

Comment: Perhaps [security.se] is more appropriate?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for example, requests RESTFul API from static front-end page.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121971/will-same-site-cookies-be-sufficent-protection-against-csrf-and-xss